# NameValueCollection returns Length Property instead of Name Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could someone shed some light on this my NameValueCollection returns the Length property instead of Name and Value could some show me what im doing wrong here. I can't set the DataTextField or DataValueField for the dropdownlist it just gives me length.

```
    public NameValueCollection GetDisplayForumGroups()
    {
        using (CMSEntities db = new CMSEntities())
        {

            var forums = (from x in db.Forums where x.ParentID == null select new { Name = x.Title, Value = x.ForumID }); 
            NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();

            foreach (var forum in forums)
            {
                collection.Add(forum.Name, forum.Value.ToString());
            }

            return collection;
        }
    }


    public Dictionary<string, int> GetDisplayForumGroups()
    {
        using (CMSEntities db = new CMSEntities())
        {

            Dictionary<string, int> forums = (from x in db.Forums where x.ParentID == null select x).ToDictionary(x => x.Title, x => x.ForumID); 


            return forums;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are showing us the wrong code; Where is the code that sets the properties of your DropDownList? If you are seeing a Length instead of Name/Value, you've set something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind directly to a `NameValueCollection` since it doesn't provide a suitable enumerator. The standard enumerator enumerates through the keys only.

Then again you shouldn't be using a `NameValueCollection` for this in the first place, you should use the generic `Dictionary` unless you need multiple values per key (and even then there are better alternatives for most cases). There's even a Linq method for automagically making a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, int> forums = (from x
                                  in db.Forums
                                  where x.ParentID == null
                                  select x)
                                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Title, x => x.ForumID);
```

Comment: Thankyou for you're answer. I was following some peoples examples with NameValueCollection for the DropDownList and one person couldn't get it to work I fell into the same trap!

Comment: Can you use a Dictionary object with the GridView?

Comment: @KDM: I don't see why not, seems like a odd place to put use a dictionary though. What would you do with the gridview?